# How to replace characters in math equations in Microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word

For example, I want to replace the all variable "c" in all math equations of this paragraph by "x". It seems an ordinary task, but I find it very difficult to do so. I am not sure, but the normal replace dialog seems not supporting this.

> [image]

Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid your only option is to do it manually.

Comment: @MátéJuhász One possible work-around is to [unzip the .docx file](https://superuser.com/a/278262/269915) and edit the `word/document.xml` file. (An advanced text editor is probably needed to facilitate editing. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a substitution in math zones, you have to work with Unicode codes that represent characters in those zones. Here's how to do that:

1. Place the cursor at the right of the character you want to replace, then press <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> to see the code.
2. Copy or type the code in the *Find* area of the *Find & replace* window. Press <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> again.
3. Do the same with the character you want to use (you may need to temporary type it in a math zone to see its corresponding code).
4. Copy or type this other code in the *Replace* area of the *Find & replace* window. Press <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> again.
5. Click on *Replace* button.

**Note**: Combination <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> shows the Unicode encoding; pressing again the keys <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> gives you back the character.

Answer (score -1):

1- Write the variable x then take a copy of it
2- Select the variable c and use find and replace tool "ctrl+h" + esc
4- Select the whole paragraph in which you want to replace the variable c with x
5- ctrl+h again (you will see the variable c in find what) + select find + select find in + the current selection + esc
6- now you will see all c variable selected in the paragraph
7- replace by the x that you are already has copied :)
Done

you may also use find in the main document and replace through the whole document

Comment: This answer seems incomplete.   It also lacks formatting.